# fullpage.js onLeave not working when using anchor first time

Tags: jquery, html, fullpage.js

Ok, I experience a very strange issue with fullpage.js.
Here is my code:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction){                
            if (index == 1 && direction =='down') {               
                $('.titlea').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 300, function(){$('.titleb').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});
            } else if (index == 2 && direction =='down' || index == 2 && direction =='up') {
                $('.aboutme').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
            } else if (index == 3 && direction =='down' || index == 3 && direction =='up') {
                $('.menume').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 100);
                $('.rubrika1').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){$('.rubrika2').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);});
                $('.rubrika3').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){$('.rubrika4').hide("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);});
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index){
            if (index == 1){
                $('.titlea').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200, function(){$('.titleb').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 200);});               
            } else if (index == 2) {
                 $('.aboutme').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
            } else if (index == 3) {
                $('.menume').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
$('.home').delay(100).show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
                $('.rubrika1').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){$('.rubrika2').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);});
                $('.rubrika3').show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 300, function(){$('.rubrika4').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 200);});
            }
        }   

    });
```

and html for menu part:

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="menume">
<a href="#firstPage"><div data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="home"></div></a>
</ul>


<div id="fullpage">
<div class="section">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="section">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="section">blah blah blah</div>
<div class="section">blah blah blah</div>
</div>
```

So the problem is that when I click on that menu button with #firstPage anchor, it links me to the first section as needed, but onLeave animation doesn't work. All elements that are supposed to hide when the anchor is clicked, stay. And also, afterLoad of the first section doesn't show the animations of the first section either, when I click anchor to it.

If I just scroll down or up - all animations work. Now here is the weirdest part, after I click that anchor and animations don't work, when I scroll down and click on that anchor again - everything starts working properly. All elements get animated and hide/show as needed. What could it be? Why anchor link doesn't trigger animations for the first time, but triggers it later?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved an issue by enabling lockAnchors:true in plugin settings.